# For loop in nohup

Tags: shell-script, nohup

I am trying to run bash script which run 8 for loops simultaneously.

One of the for loop likes below

```
for i in 00 01 02 03 04 ; do cat $INDIR/sys*$1.$i*csv | \ 
awk -F '\xac' 'BEGIN{OFS=";";} ($4 == 10)  { $1=$1; print }'> $OUTDIR/$1_$i.csv
```

So I have converted into following syntax to run with `nohup`

```
nohup bash -c 'for i in 00 01 02 03 04; do cat $INDIR/rti*$1.$i*csv| \
awk -F \'\\xac\' \'BEGIN{OFS=\";\";} ($4==10) { $1=$1; print }\'>$OUTDIR/$i.csv;done' &
```

But I am getting following error

```
test.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 9: `nohup bash -c 'for i in 00 01 02 03 04; do cat $INDIR/rti*$1.$i*csv|awk -F \'\\xac\' \'BEGIN{OFS=\";\";} ($4==10) { $1=$1; print }\'>$OUTDIR/$i.csv;done' & '
```

I also tried with following code changes

> ```
> nohup sh -c '<code>'
> nohup /bin/bash -c '<code>'
> \'\xac\'
> ```

but no progress.

However, my for loop works without `nohup`.

Comment: The root issue here is the single quotes, backslashes don't work inside them, so you have `'for ...|awk -F \'` quoted, then the rest is unquoted since the following single-quotes are all escaped.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier (read: more read- and maintainable) if you divide your code into two scripts: One to execute the actual function(s), and one to start them. Sample code for the latter:

```
for i in 00 01 02 03 04; do
    nohup /path/to/workerScript.sh ${i}
done
```

If you want to keep the logic in a single script you can still use this approach:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    for i in 00 01 02 03 04; do
        nohup $0 ${i}
    done

    exit 0
fi

# Rest of the logic follows
```

Comment: Hello Murphy
I already have this solution and it works very well. But I am looking one script way :)   thanks for your reply

Comment: @Murat You can have that and still keep the script readable. I expanded my example.